# Defining the file a UIImage will use (Swift)

Tags: ios, uiimage, swift

So I looked around the developer library on apple's site and I couldn't find any documentation that said how to state what file (like a png) to use for a UIImage using the swift language. 
So I try experimenting with this code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var maintitle: UIImageView

var bigtitle: UIImage!
var smalltitle: UIImage!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib. 

    func startAnimating(){
        var animatedtitle: AnyObject[] = [bigtitle, smalltitle]
        var animationDuration: NSTimeInterval = 0.15
        var animationRepeatCount: Int = 0
    }
}
```

What I was trying to do there was animate a never ending series of two images. I defined two UIImages (bigtitle & small title) and was wondering how I define wat .png's to use for those UIImage's. I know this is a very basic and novice question but any help would be enjoyed.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Even though you are using Swift, all the classes that come from `UIKit` and other libraries still are written in Objective-C.

There is no difference in the interfaces to these libraries, just the syntax.

In this case, you need to use the object construction syntax:

```
var image = UIImage(named:"ImageName")
```

Comment: as well as just using, var img = UIImage(named:"myImage")

Comment: Should image be optional? I think with new swift version you have to declare it optional as init method may return nil.