# Swift: Can not use NSImage .imageNamed

Tags: swift, osx-yosemite

I am seeing imageNamed deprecated (or removed) from available options When I do the following:

```
       var statusImage:NSImage? = nil

       self.statusImage = NSImage .ImageNamed....
```

[image]

I have tried the Swift document provided by Apple and other placed.This seemed very trivial but  could not find the solution for imageNamed. Am I missing something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Defining the file a UIImage will use (Swift)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049537/defining-the-file-a-uiimage-will-use-swift)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use [`init(named: String!)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSImage/imageNamed:) instead: call it like `NSImage(named: "foo")`.

The compiler automatically remaps ObjC class methods that are named as convenience constructors to work as Swift initializers. If a class method follows the naming convention of a convenience constructor (e.g. `+[SomeThing thingWithFoo: bar:]`), Swift remaps it to an initializer (e.g. call `SomeThing(foo: aFoo, bar: aBar)`). This also goes for a few methods that Apple identified as working like a convenience constructor (as in the case of `imageNamed:`).

In most cases, if you finish typing the class-method-style call to a convenience constructor, the compiler will give you an error that tells you how it's been remapped:

```
error: 'imageNamed' is unavailable: use object construction 'NSImage(named:)'
```

More generally, you can look at the autogenerated module "header" for an API symbol in Xcode by cmd-clicking that symbol (e.g. `NSImage`) in the editor, or look in Xcode's documentation viewer or the online reference docs for that API, to find the Swift syntax for using it.