# How do I define an image for the UIImageViewer in Swift?

Tags: ios, image, swift

I'm making an iOS app, and I'm completely new to Swift/Objective-C. I'm trying to set the picture that will be displayed in the `UIImageViewer` and I can't find where to add the file.

Comment: Are you writing the app in Swift or in Objective-C?

Comment: Does this put you on the right track? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049537/defining-the-file-a-uiimage-will-use-swift

Comment: do you want to display the image ? or you want to store the image in your document folder of your app?

Comment: I want to display the image. @BigRon it does help but not what I'm looking for.

Comment: I am writing this in swift @sbooth

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand what you want, you can set a picture to the UIImageView by selecting the UIImageView in your storyboard and going to the right panel like below.

[image]

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking to do, but when I try it I don't get any options to select. Do I need to import the files somehow?

Comment: @JustinSafa I assumed you had the files inside your project. You can import them to images.xcassets or inside a new folder.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks everyone for the help. I found out my second issue. I'll post quick instructions should anyone else need to know how in the future

1. Import images into the Images.xcassets file
2. Click on Image Viewer and on the drop down bar on the right click your image
3. Enjoy